# how to break column data of a single row in datagridview manually?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, newline

**code**

```
while (dr.Read())  
{  
    string s = dr["Title"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + dr["Description"].ToString();  
    row["Title"]= s.Trim();  
    dt.Rows.Add(row["Title"]);  
}
```

i want to break the line in my datagridview.i have row value with "name subject",i want to split it as "name"(newline)"subject" in the same row itself.

Comment: Why would you tag it as asp.net if it is a winforms app?

Comment: it's clumsy of me,excuse it...

Comment: what would be the solution for gridview (not datagridview)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the problem that line returns are not being displayed in cells in your DataGridView?

If so you need to set the [DataGridViewCellStyle.WrapMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode.aspx) of the Column you want to see line returns on to [DataGridViewTriState.True](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtristate.aspx).

After you do that the Cells in that column will display line breaks within a cell using `Environment.NewLine`, `\n`, etc.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response it is working for me Thank you sooo....much.. I want Set Text as bold Before Brake text..Is it possible plese help me...

Comment: @user872998 You can set the text of an entire Cell to bold using the DataGridView CellFormatting event but I don't think you can set a portion of a cell's text to bold using this technique. Sounds like that would be an excellent SO question though

Comment: So there is no option to set the Portion of the text as bold in win forms?

Comment: @user872998 I don't know any way to set a portion of the text in a DataGridView cell to bold.

Comment: ok thank you so..much Jay Riggs thanks a lot for your valuable helping

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `someColumn.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;` on whatever column you want for it to display multiple lines in.

Answer (score -1):

did you try using: `dt.Rows.Add(row["Title"].ToString().Replace(" ", "\r\n"));`

Comment: if i use that every space in  the column data replace by newline.